# Sonata Admin v 3.4.0 fontawesome icons missing on list/edit pages

Tags: font-awesome, symfony, sonata-admin

I have a problem with icons not showing up when creating/editing/listing.
On dashboard everything is ok. I have checked their demo and there are fine but the same font errors occurs. When changing page, ex. edit, the url for font awesome changes and also the version, i didn't found where. I added fontawesome to web/fonts folders and this is why is ok in dashboard.
Why is the font url changing with page and where is the versions 4.2 coming from?

[font awesome error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8vUb.png)

```
assetic:
debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
filters:
    cssrewrite: ~
assets:
    sonata_admin_css:
         %kernel.root_dir%/../web/bundles/sonatacore/vendor/components-font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css
    sonata_front_css:
         %kernel.root_dir%/../web/bundles/sonatacore/vendor/components-font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css
```

Answer (score 0):

FontAwesome can be found in the [SonataCoreBundle](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataCoreBundle/tree/3.x/Resources/public/vendor/components-font-awesome). You should include the css (in your assetic config). Below is an example which also uses the page bundle for sonata_front_css.

```
# app/config/assetic.yml
assetic:
    assets:
        # ...
        sonata_admin_css:
            # ...
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../web/bundles/sonatacore/vendor/components-font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css
        # ...
        sonata_front_css:
            # ...
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../web/bundles/sonatacore/vendor/components-font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css
```

Then copy the [font](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataCoreBundle/tree/3.x/Resources/public/vendor/components-font-awesome/fonts) into the `web/fonts` directory (any best practise, someone?)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This does not work for me. I have font awesome in web/fonts and the icons are fine in main page(dashboard) but when i list or edit icons are gone.

Comment: Did you run `php app/console assets:install` after changing your assetic config? Mind sharing a part of your assetic config, your font folder etc.. Any relative sources.

Comment: I added assetic config. Yes i run command bin/console assets:install --symlink . The problem is that the url to fonts is rewritten on page change. Ex: on dashboard i have http://workapp.lo/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.2.0 and on list page i have http://workapp.lo/admin/app/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.2.0